# Redirecting to MyDomain URL

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, authentication, mydomain

We set up SSO with Auth.Provider in Salesforce. We deployed My Domain and linked the auth provider to it. When a user navigates to the My Domain URL, they are automatically redirected to the auth provider for sign-in.

I created a custom URL to redirect to My Domain, but quickly realized that a redirect cannot be sent to a My Domain (instead of going to the My Domain page, it goes to `test.salesforce.com`).

My auth provider cannot set up a unique page for our SF environment.

If we want a custom URL that redirects to My Domain, can we set it up through SF

[image: Site]

[image: Redirect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Site and add a [redirect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_redirects.htm&type=5) from a Site URL to a destination. The destination can be any relative or absolute URL, including a MyDomain URL.

Out of the box, the hostname of the site will be auto-generated and added to a DNS for you by Salesforce. You have an option of using your [own, custom domain](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335296&type=1&mode=1) controlled by your own DNS instead of having the Site default to blah.force.com. While this is technically possible, you'll need to jump through a lot of hoops. It is much easier to stick with an auto-generated Site hostname.

Comment: So I created a site /login and I'm trying to redirect my /login page to my My Domain page but it isn't working. Am I missing something? ----
Source URL: /login,  
Target URL: test--Partial.cs29.my.salesforce.com

Comment: Looks right. How does it not work?

Comment: When I put in the *.force.com/login page - I am not redirected to My Domain. The URL is still the force.com/login page. Does it take awhile to take effect?

Comment: No, it takes effect immediately. Make sure your Site and redirect are both active (there's an Active checkbox) and nothing else is mapped to /login

Comment: I tried redirecting to google.com as a test - this wont work either.. I'll try to upload some pics if you can assist.

Comment: Might be a sandbox vs prod issue. Try it in a Production org (Developer Edition orgs are Production)

Comment: Hi! Sorry - I have another follow up. So I successfully set up a redirected to My Domain. But when I set up a redirect from my custom url (not a url maintained in SF)  to my force.com page - it didn't work.. It went to cs68.salesforce.com instead of the My Domain page.

Comment: Essentially I'm routing: custom URL -> force.com -> My Domain

Comment: If force.com -> My Domain works but custom URL -> force.com -> My Domain doesn't work, it's likely an issue with the first hop but might be something else. If you think it's a Salesforce issue, post a new question. Non-Salesforce issues are best asked on [so] or another SE, perhaps [webmasters.se] or [security.se]